# Whats the most efficient way to sort elements of an array based on frequency of elements

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, hashmap

I have an array and i've used the following method to sort the array based on the frequency of the elements.

1. I store the elements and their respective frequency as key value pair.
2. I store the values(frequency of the elements) in an array
3. I sort the array in descending order
4. I print the keys corresponding the values

```
public void sort(int a[])
    {
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> hs = new HashMap<>();

        for(int i = 0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            Integer j = new Integer(a[i]);
            if(hs.containsKey(j))
                hs.put(j,hs.get(j)+1);
            else
                hs.put(j,1);
        }
        Integer g[] = new Integer[hs.size()];
        int v= 0;
        for(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry : hs.entrySet())
            g[v++] = entry.getValue();

        for(int i = 0;i<v-1;i++)
            {
                for(int j=i+1;j<v;j++)
                {
                    if(g[j]>g[i])
                    {
                        int temp = g[j];
                        g[j] = g[i];
                        g[i] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
   int i=0;
    while(i != v){
    for(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry : hs.entrySet())
    {
            if(g[i] == entry.getValue())
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() +" = "+ g[i++]);
    }
    }


    }
```

Is there any short and efficient way to do this please suggest.

Comment: allowed to use java 8 and plus??

Comment: `Arrays.stream(yourArray).boxed().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))`

Comment: @Michael , `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))` will end up in `Map<Integer, Long>` , but OP needs `Map<Integer, Integer>` so using `Collectors.reducing(0, e -> 1, Integer::sum)` will be best here.

Comment: @VishwaRatna OP doesn't "need" a `Map<Integer, Integer>` - the goal is to sort the array by the specified order, not to create a map of a specific type. The map is an auxiliary data structure and can be easily changed to type `Map<Integer, Long>` if that simplifies the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a list from the map's entrySet and then sort the list using a custom comparator which compares based on the values of the map.

1. Creating a List from the Map's entrySet - use the constructor which takes another collection as an argument.
2. Sorting the list - Collections.sort using a Comparator implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know about short, but you can implement a simple [priority queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) which makes your code more readable. Time complexity is `O(n log(n))`.

In the priority queue, we will just have elements with higher frequency at the top.

**Snippet:**

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main{
    static class Element{
        int value,freq;
        Element(int value,int freq){
            this.value = value;
            this.freq = freq;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sort(new int[]{2,2,4,5,7,6,4,8,3,9,5,7,2});
    }

    public static void sort(int a[]){
        Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;++i){
            map.merge(a[i], 1, Integer::sum);
        }

        PriorityQueue<Element> pq = new PriorityQueue<Element>(1000,(c,d) -> (d.freq - c.freq));
        for(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> m : map.entrySet()){
            pq.offer(new Element(m.getKey(),m.getValue()));
        }

        while(!pq.isEmpty()){
            Element e = pq.poll();
            System.out.println(e.value + " => " + e.freq);
        }
    }
}
```

**Demo:** https://onlinegdb.com/HJpdDX7bI

Comment: you can use `map.merge(a[i], 1, Integer::sum)` instead of those two instructions in your first `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

From Java-8 onwards:

```
  int [] array = {2,2,4,5,7,6,4,8,3,9,5,7,2};
  Map<Integer, Integer> collect = Arrays.stream(array).boxed()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.reducing(0, e -> 1, Integer::sum)));
  System.out.println(collect);
```

Beaware,If you use `Collectors.counting()` then you will end up getting `Map<Integer, Long>` , but as per your solution it seems you want `Map<Integer, Integer>`, therefore use `Collectors.reducing(0, e -> 1, Integer::sum)`

Comment: The original question is unclear about what 'efficient' means. If it means: In simple, short code – this certainly wins the prize ;) - but this algorithm is not necessarily particularly memory efficient, given that it has to dip into boxed territory.

Answer (score 0):

With an additional memory load that is vastly smaller than your example (only 200% extra, in the worst case scenario), and a performance characteristic of O(n log n); I'm pretty sure you can't algorithmically beat it, though with a lot of extra work you can reduce the memory load down to worst-case 100% extra; probably not worth doing.

The algorithm, in a nutshell:

Make a new array of longs. Each long is bitpacked; it contains 2 separate pieces of info: The lower 32 bits are for the number as normal (this fits, as ints are 32 bits); the higher 32 bits are used to store frequency (how often the number occurs in the input).

In order to efficiently make your new long array, first sort your input array; this takes O(n log n), and means you can then loop once through your input array to create your long array. Then, sort that one, which will put the most frequent element at the back. Reverse it if need be, if you want most frequent in the front. (the higher frequency bitpacked numbers are larger, as its higher 32-bit is the highest); this is another O(n log n) op. So, it's 2 O(n log n) ops and a single O(n) op, for a grand total of O(n log n).

Relevant bits of API and java knowledge:

- Sorting int and long arrays: `java.util.Arrays.sort(int[] or long[])`
- bitpacking: You need the `|` operator and the `<<` operator. To bitpack 2 ints into a long, for example:

  int count = 5; // represents how often 'number' shows.
  int number = 85;
  long packed = (((long) count) << 32) | number;
- bit unpacking: to turn a packed long back into the component parts:

  long packed = ....; // from above calculation
  int count = (int) (packed >> 32); // will be 5
  int number = (int) packed; // will be 85

You need to do some fancy footwork to deal with the long[] array containing the packed info; after all, this array has likely fewer elements (given an input [1,2,5,1,2], your packed long array has 3 entries: The packed result of [{count=2, number=1}, {count=2, number=2} and {count=1, number=5}], so only 3 entries; either first go through your sorted input array once to figure out how large it needs to be, then do it again to fill it, or make the long array as large as your input array (which is how large it has to be in the worst case, which is when all the numbers in the input array are unique), and write code to know that a 0 in your long array is to be ignored.

To fill the long array, just walk through your sorted input array. It'll look like [1,1,2,2,5] which you need to convert into [packed(2,1),packed(2,2),packed(1,5)]. I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet another solution:

```
public static void sort(int[] a) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> hs = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        Integer j = a[i];
        if (hs.containsKey(j)) {
            hs.put(j, hs.get(j) + 1);
        } else {
            hs.put(j, 1);
        }
    }
    List<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(hs.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(list, (x,y)->{
        int r = x.getValue().compareTo(y.getValue());
        if (r == 0) {
            r = x.getKey().compareTo(y.getKey());
        }
        return r;
    });
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : list) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```